# training and development data, ValueError: dimension mismatch

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I built the following classification model:

```
def buildData(x):
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(x)
    tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(X_train_counts)
    X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
    return X_train_tf

x, y = parseXml('data/training.xml')
xDev, yDev = parseXml('data/dev.xml')

x = buildData(x)
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(x, y)
predicted = clf.predict(x)
print( 'Accuracy: ', accuracy_score(y, predicted))
```

I fit the model using the training data "x" and I test it also on "x" ..

the problem is, if I want to predict it on xDev (predicted = clf.predict(xDev)) it shows an error.

and As I think this is because that the data is not prepared (in a Tf_idf matrix shape), so I passed the xDev data to the same function:

```
xDev = buildData(xDev)
```

to prepare it, but unfortunately, this error appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/BG/Desktop/P2/E2.py", line 43, in <module>
    predicted = clf.predict(xDev)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 66, in predict
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 725, in
_joint_log_likelihood
    return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T) +   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 135, in safe_sparse_dot
    ret = a * b   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 476, in
__mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch') ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save and persist tf_transformer from the first (training) call. tf_transformer is dependent on the vocabulary of the data  you feed it. In your case the corpus vocabulary (i.e. set of all the unique words in the combined documents) is likely different between x and xDev. This is common in text classification use cases. For example, you training x may have 1000 words and your xDev may have 800 words (different or similar).

If you persist tf_transformer from the first call to buildData() and transform the xDev data using the same tf_transformer instead of recreating another one again in buildData(), the error will go away.

In other words tf_transformer should be created once, fit into training data, and reused. It should not be recreated every time for test or production data as your code does when you call buildData again on your test data. Here's [a blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a) about an alternate way to create an NLP/classification pipeline that reuses a transformer created once.

TL;DR - set the variable below one time in your application workflow, not multiple times

```
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(X_train_counts)
```